# Why is Airflow not recognizing my bash command?

Tags: python, bash, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I created a DAG from a py file. When I trigger the DAG, it gets hung up on the first task. My log states this :

```
[2022-04-16 20:51:05,371] {subprocess.py:74} INFO - Running command: ['bash', '-c', 'wget "https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DB0250EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Final%20Assignment/tolldata.tgz"']
[2022-04-16 20:51:05,403] {subprocess.py:85} INFO - Output:
[2022-04-16 20:51:05,406] {subprocess.py:89} INFO - bash: wget: command not found
[2022-04-16 20:51:05,407] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2022-04-16 20:51:05,499] {taskinstance.py:1703} ERROR - Task failed with exception
```

It's driving me crazy

Comment: Where is `wget` installed? What's your `PATH` configured to? Only commands installed at a location currently set in the `PATH` can be run.

Comment: It looks like `wget` is not in whatever `PATH` it's using (which is probably different from the `PATH` in your interactive shells). Find the full path to `wget` (`which wget` should tell you), and use that instead. BTW, is there a reason it's running the command via a shell (the `bash -c` part) rather than directly?

Comment: Note too that many modern operating systems don't include wget out-of-the-box anymore at all; `curl` is starting to overtake it in popularity.

Comment: (and I agree with Gordon re: the implication that you'd be better off getting bash out of the picture and running ['/usr/bin/wget', 'https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DB0250EN-SkillsNetwork/labs/Final%20Assignment/tolldata.tgz']` directly, after adjusting `/usr/bin` for wherever your copy of wget is actually installed at).

Comment: ...the other thing here -- does airflow not give you any way to call native Python code? Python has some really great HTTP(s) libraries built-in (and the 3rd-party but ubiquitous [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package as an even more powerful out-of-tree alternative); you shouldn't be needing to use an external command in the first place.

Comment: I'm very much a beginner. This is part of an assignment for a class I'm taking on EDX. Even when I already have the file downloaded it, Airflow stalls out.